# How to overwrite a subscription

Tags: rxjs

I have a situation where I need to place a subscription inside a function, which is called multiple times.

My question is, if I call the function 3 times, do I create 3 new subscriptions or does the original subscription get overwritten?

The reason behind this question, is that I want to avoid creating multiple subscriptions, so as not to cause a memory leak.

```js
var observable = Rx.Observable;
var subscription = new Rx.Subscription();

var numbers = observable.from([1,2,3,4,5,6]);

function foo(){

    subscription = numbers.subscribe( val => console.log("numbers subscribes",val) )

    subscription.unsubscribe();

}

foo();
foo();
foo();
```

**UPDATE:**

I have been asked to display the actual code from my project. I have left out quite a lot of code for simplicty, but the references to:

```
this.messages
```

Refer to an observable that emits an array.

I want to remove this line safely:

```
this.subscriptionPostMessages.unsubscribe();
```

**Here is the code:**

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpEventType, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Message } from '../message/message.model';
import { GlobalsService } from '../globals/globals.service';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable()
export class MessagesService implements OnDestroy {

  messages: Observable<Message[]>;
  postMessages: Observable<Message[]>;

  subscriptionPostMessages: Subscription;

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
              public globalsService: GlobalsService) {


  postMessage(message: Message): void {
    const body = {
      messageid: message.id,
      filename: ''
    };
    const requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const headers = {
      headers: requestHeaders
    };
    this.http.post(this.globalsService.baseUrl + environment.ajax_dir + '/ajax-ng-post-message-module.cfm', body, headers).map(
      (res: Response) => {
        if('filename' in res && res['filename'] !== ''){
          this.postMessages = this.addFileNameToMessage(res['messageid'], res['filename']);
          this.subscriptionPostMessages = this.postMessages.subscribe( (messages: Message[]) => {
          });
          this.subscriptionPostMessages.unsubscribe();
        }
        return res;
      })
      .subscribe();
  }

  addFileNameToMessage(id: string, filename: string): Observable<Message[]> {
    return this.messages.map( (messages: Message[]) => {
      messages.map( (message: Message) => {
        if(message.id === id){
          message.file.filename = filename;
          message.file.value = '';
        }
      })
      return messages;
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscriptionPostMessages) {
      this.subscriptionPostMessages.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

Does:

```
this.subscriptionPostMessages
```

Get overwritten each time:

```
postMessage()
```

Gets called?

In other words, will I only ever have one subscription active at any one time?

Comment: If you subscribe to Time Magazine and your neighbor does the same then they don't get your copy. On the other hand the stream in your example completes, so where could the memory leak emerge?

Comment: @a better oliver Thanks for the comment. What happens, if I remove 'subscription.unsubscribe()'? Would this piece of code still be OK?

Comment: Yes, if you also remove `var subscription`. But keep in mind that if a stream does not complete (e.g. one created with `interval()`) you need to unsubscribe like you correctly suggested.

Comment: @a better oliver Thanks. This is the answer I wanted...

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke your code as supplied you will not have multiple subscriptions lingering around because you `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` in the same function call. Note that this will result in unexpected behaviour with regards to the amount of values you will receive in your `onNext` callback of the subscribe given the async nature of RxJs.

I have the feeling you are almost stumbling upon a rx-antipattern but you would need to give more information about what you want to archieve to give you a better answer about that.

Comment: _"given the async nature of RxJs"_ Care to explain? There is nothing asynchronous in the example.

Comment: @Mark van Straten What would happen if I remove the 'subscription.unsubscribe()'? Would there still only be one subscription at any one time? I am trying to understand whether the same subscription is being overwritten, each time 'foo' is being called?

Comment: if you remove the `unsubscribe()` you are only overwriting your local variable `subscription` and end up with multiple dangling subscriptions (memory leak). Since your example is finite these will end but be very careful if you would do this with for instance `Observable.interval()` ad infinitum

Comment: @abetteroliver what i mean with the async nature is that this example is sync and works because of this. Once you would go async the code would behave differently leading to difficult to reason about bugs.

Comment: @Mark van Straten There is no local subscription. Am I not overwriting the global subscription, each time I call foo()?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use the 'subscription.unsubscribe()' statement for lots of reasons. Is there another way, I can unsubscribe each time? I was hoping that overwriting the value would do the job?

Comment: @CharlesRobertson It really depends on how your code is structured. you can for instance make an eventEmitter `onClick` stream and use that as a `.takeUntil()` on your subscription. This is also the reason why i asked for more information in my original answer so somebody can provide you with a more precise answer.

Comment: @Mark van Straten OK. I will update my answer & put the full code up today. It is written using Angular 5, by the way...